# Generating a PDF Index with ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm generating PDF files through ReportLab, but i can't find any documentation on how to generate an index linking to the file pages. Does ReportLab support this type of feature, or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of time searching i came up with an `anchor` solution. Although i feel it was not the perfect solution for me, i hope it helps someone in need.

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFont
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, PageBreak, SimpleDocTemplate, Spacer

registerFont(TTFont('Calibri', 'Calibri.ttf')) # Just some font imports
registerFont(TTFont('Calibri-Bold', 'calibrib.ttf'))

pH = ParagraphStyle(name = 'Header', fontName = 'Calibri-Bold', fontSize = 13, leftIndent = 20, firstLineIndent = -20, spaceBefore = 10, leading = 16)
sH = ParagraphStyle(name = 'SubHeader', fontName = 'Calibri', fontSize = 12, leftIndent = 40, firstLineIndent = -20, spaceBefore = 5, leading = 16)

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('Reports\\PDFname.pdf')
story = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]

story.append(Paragraph('<a href = page3.html#0>1. First Title</a>', pH)) # Linking the anchor to reference 0
story.append(Paragraph('<a href = page3.html#1>1.1. First Subtitle</a>', sH)) # Linking the anchor to reference 1
story.append(PageBreak())

story.append(Paragraph('<a name = page3.html#0></a> 1. First Title', pH)) # Creating anchor with reference 0
story.append(Paragraph('<a name = page3.html#1></a><br/> 1.1. First Subtitle', style)) # Creating anchor with reference 1

doc.build(story)
```